# How to get specific edittext value from listview onclick item?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have 2 edittext in each list item, so onclick a item i am currently getting all the text at once displayed in a list item, but i want them seperately.

**xml**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/roll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>
```

**onclick function**

```
listviewQuestion.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String questionid = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                Toast.makeText(QuestionListActivity.this, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

**current output**

```
{name=abc,roll=123}
```

But i want to extract name and roll seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try the code below?

```
listviewQuestion.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        EditText editTextName = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText editTextRoll = view.findViewById(R.id.roll);

        String name = editTextName != null ? editTextName.getText().toString() : "NULL";
        String roll = editTextRoll != null ? editTextRoll.getText().toString() : "NULL";

        Toast.makeText(QuestionListActivity.this, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

If does not work, I'll remove.
I think this way you can read the text of each `EditText`